# p5.js input position relative to canvas

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, p5.js

Here's what I have:

```
function setup() {
  var cnv = createCanvas(960,540);
  cnv.parent("sketchHolder");
  background('white');

  var input = createInput();
  input.position(10,10);
  input.parent("sketchHolder");
}
```

I have a div named "sketchHolder" centered with css. I am trying to make the input position relative to the canvas, but it is positioned on the entire webpage outside on the canvas instead. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can't you get the position of the canvas and set the position of the input relative to that?

Comment: It changes when the browser resizes.

Comment: Have you tried googling how to use CSS to specify the location of an element relative to another element?

Comment: I didn't know that was possible. I'll look into it, thanks. But if someone has an answer to how to position it relative to the canvas, I feel like that'd be a cleaner solution.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm suggesting. You can use CSS to do just that. My guess is that's what the `input.position()` function is doing behind the scenes anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function setup() {
  var cnv = createCanvas(960, 540);
  cnv.parent("sketchHolder");
  background("blue");

  var input = createInput();
  input.position(10, 10);
  input.parent("sketchHolder");
}
```

```css
#sketchHolder {
  width: 960px;
  height: 540px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.11/p5.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.11/addons/p5.dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="sketchHolder"></div>
```

[Codepen link](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xrVgaN)